# IHS and plugin in WebSphere Application

Tags: websphere

I wonder how IBM HTTP Server pass requests to WebSphere Application.
Currently there are four IBM HTTP Servers installed separately and
There is only one webserver definition in WebSphere console.

I thought there should be four webserver definition to create plugin and communicate and pass a request to WAS because there are four IHS servers.

so my question is how each IHS server pass a request to WAS with one web server?

Comment: Are the web servers configured behind a load balancer with a common external IP address? If so, the web servers could be configured with the same plugin configuration file but the file would need to be moved to the web server manually rather than using WebSphere.

Comment: Hi Betsy Riggins, yes web servers are behind L4 switch. yes it seems plugin file is manually moved to each web server. thank your for your response. I now understand current setting. :-)